# google tag manager v2 basic configuration I'm not getting hits on google analytics

Tags: cordova, analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm working on a cordova/phonegap project. I'm using a plugin for GTM that allows me to track events.

The problem is that I'm not getting hits on google analytics.

According with the developer it's working fine, and from my testing, everything seems ok, no errors at all on Javascript console, and all events are firing correctly.

Since I'm new with GTM, I believe that I'm missing something on configureting it.

These are my confs:

First, the GA tag:
[image: Tag view of GA]

I used the built-in trigger "Any event" so it triggers every time an event is registered.

This is the config I set for the GA tag, I want it to trigger on every event, that's why I left empty the fields
[image: GA tag configuration]

And the GTM container type I'm using is "mobile".

For I what haver been reading so far is far different from GTM V1 where I had to create macros, and another tag to be able to track this same information.

I tried manual triggers such as, "Event matches RegEx .*" (which I believe it's the same as the built-in "Any event" trigger)

Answer (score 0):

You have to fill in the Category and Action field at the very least for GA to register a hit. (Categoira, Accion, I guess)

Those aren't filter fields, they are the fields sent in an event hit.  You will need to use something like the macros {{element text}} or something you want to record to see hits in GA.

Check out the [Event Tracking Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) by Google for more details.

Comment: On my app I'm tracking events sending all that info (category, action,label and value) and I want to track all the events regardless the category or action.
On GTM V2 there ain't macros anymore, the closest thing there is, are the built-in variables, and the one related to this is "Event" but for what I found this variable it's only a string, a value attached to a the key "event" from dataLayer.

So I can only use {{Event}}, and I don't know how to create a variable like {{category}} or {{action}}

Comment: If it where possible to use a RegEx like .* for those fields, could be a solution I guess.

Comment: It sounds like you're one step ahead of what GTM offers.  The event template is for sending data in, and the viewing of all events you woudl like to see is something you could do in the GA interface.

Also bear in mind that events here have two meanings - javascript type events that trigger data, and GA events that are recorded.  It is confusing :)

Comment: For now, you can enter strings such as Category="debug".  Also check out the GTM event guide if you haven't already: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#events